# Multiple structures sharing the same entries?

Tags: entries, structure, ordering

I'm working on a site that currently has one structure ("projects") that organizes my entries for each specific project. In the admin I can reorder these entries manually... so far so good!

But now, I was wondering if I could have two different structures: 1. for "featured projects" on the home page and 2. for a "project index" - both that I could reorder manually but in a different order from one another. Does that make sense?

So I was wondering if it was possible to have two different structures share the same set of entries?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: It's no possible to have the same entries in two different structures, but if it's just for sorting perhaps you could add a custom field to the entry type?

Comment: Interesting... thanks for your reply. So I could add a field for "sort number" to sort the entries on one page by number and on the other manually?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It might be a bit annoyingly manual anytime you want to change the order - for example, if #5 was now #2, you'd have to edit 4 entries, but I think it's preferential to managing two structures, which would quickly fall out of sync.

Comment: If you want have control over the ordering of projects in different contexts (like on a homepage or other page), I would use an Entries field and pull in the projects entries you want to manipulate and re-order them there. For example, let's say you have a Homepage Single, and you want to list your projects on the homepage in a certain order, or only include some of them, you can create a Entries field on the Homepage Single and pick and choose the projects you want.

Comment: @CraftQuest Thanks for this idea... I've looked into it but I don't quite understand what an Entries Field is used for. I set up an entries field and a single section that brings in all the entries of a certain type (called projects). But when I try to output the specific field from the specific entries (projects) it's not really working... is the whole point of the entries field just to show a list of entries instead of being able to access the fields within them? I was also looking into relations but I'm not sure how I would specify those specific fields.

Comment: The entries field allows you to access all of the fields on the related entry as described here: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#querying-elements-with-entries-fields

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up creating an entries field in a single section and after wrestling with the code a bit I was able to get it to output in my template. It's great because I can manually sort the entries in the entries field as well as in my other structure... so I have a different sort for my home page and a different sort for my project index page!